# numpy.savetxt fmt='%f', appending concatenated arrays to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a function inside a class that it's called inside a while loop.
This function gets 2 6x6 matrices and returns a vector magnified by the dimensions specified in np.linspace, i.e. 6x91. I want to store these three arrays in a file (using savetxt) by concatenating them as float numbers. Below there's a sample of the function run separately from the class, which  works fine.
The problem comes when I declare the list output before the loop and by updating EulArr via a Tkinter window, append the arrays to the list. I can only save the arrays with %s format, but not anymore by %f. Why?

## LegForces(self, Li, ti)

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi
M=100.   #total estimated mass to move (upper platform+upper legs+payload)
g=9.81
nsteps= 91
Li=np.matrix([[-10.64569774, -93.1416122, 116.35191853],\
  [-10.68368329, 93.17236065, 116.35542498],\
  [85.985087,37.35196994, 116.20350534],[-75.34703551,-55.83790049, 115.44528196],\
  [-75.33938926, 55.78964226, 115.44457613],[86.0307188,-37.33446016, 116.19929305]])
ti=np.matrix([[88.15843159,88.04450508,50.10006323, -138.28903445, -138.26610178,50.2369224],\
 [-108.75675186,  108.84408749,  130.72504635, 21.82594871, -21.97569549,-130.6774372],\
 [ 119.40585161, 119.40170883,  119.23577854, 118.41560138, 118.41643529,119.24075525]])
ti=ti.T  #transpose the ti for compatible format
x_cm= 1.
y_cm= -1.
z_cm=87.752  
z=np.linspace(0,90,nsteps)  
Fx=-M*g*np.cos(pi*z/180)
Fy= M*g*np.sin(pi*z/180)
Fz=50 # including braking forces [N]
#specify here the centre of mass coordinates  retrieved from Inventor
Mx=Fz*y_cm-Fy*z_cm
My=-Fz*x_cm+Fx*z_cm
Mz=Fy*x_cm-Fx*y_cm
mc=np.zeros((6,3),'float')
ex_forces=np.array([Fx,Fy,Fz,Mx,My,Mz])
for i in range(6):
   mc[i,:]=np.cross(ti[i,:],Li[i,:])
r1=[Li[0,0],Li[1,0],Li[2,0],Li[3,0],Li[4,0],Li[5,0]]
r2=[Li[0,1],Li[1,1],Li[2,1],Li[3,1],Li[4,1],Li[5,1]]
r3=[Li[0,2],Li[1,2],Li[2,2],Li[3,2],Li[4,2],Li[5,2]]
r4=[mc[0,0],mc[1,0],mc[2,0],mc[3,0],mc[4,0],mc[5,0]]
r5=[mc[0,1],mc[1,1],mc[2,1],mc[3,1],mc[4,1],mc[5,1]]
r6=[mc[0,2],mc[1,2],mc[2,2],mc[3,2],mc[4,2],mc[5,2]]
DMatrix=np.vstack([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6])
print   'DMatrix form:\n', DMatrix
invD=np.linalg.inv(DMatrix)
print ' inv(DMatrix) is:\n', invD
legF=np.dot(ex_forces,invD)
#slice it!
legF=legF.tolist()
a,b=np.shape(legF)
print 'check identity matrix:\n', np.dot(invD,DMatrix)
print 'leg forces:\n',legF, type(legF)
newlegF=np.reshape(legF,(1,a*b))
strokeValues= np.array([[-0.3595, .1450483, -0.3131,0.4210,-0.0825,.19124]])
print 'strokeValues shape:\n', np.shape(strokeValues)
print 'leg forces vector shape:', np.shape(newlegF)
EulArr=np.array([[0.12,0.2,0,-3.,-1.,15.]]) 
output=np.concatenate((strokeValues,EulArr,newlegF),axis=1)
np.savetxt('leg_forces.dat', output,fmt=' %f')
print output ,np.shape(output)
```

The class will look like this:

```
class Hexapod(self,....):
   output=[]
   while 1:
      ...
      LegAxialF=self.LegForces(Li,ti)
      #create a list for EUl parameters which can be refreshed   
      EulArr=np.zeros((6,1),'float')
      EulArr[0]=180/pi*self.EulPhi
      EulArr[1]=180/pi*self.EulTheta
      EulArr[2]=180/pi*self.EulPsi
      EulArr[3]=self.EulX
      EulArr[4]=self.EulY
      EulArr[5]=self.EulZ-self.height 
      #print meaningful values to the specified file  
      EulArr=np.reshape(EulArr,(1,6))
      EulArrList=EulArr.tolist()
      strokes=np.reshape(strokeValues,(1,6))
      strokeList=strokes.tolist()
      output.append(np.concatenate((strokeList,\
         EulArrList,LegFList),axis=1))
      np.savetxt('act_lengths.dat', output, fmt='%f')  





def LegForces(self, Li, ti):
```

I get the following error:

```
   np.savetxt('act_lengths.dat', output, fmt='%f')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1047, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is a `list` containing `ndarray`s. I think in your code, the elements of `output` must be `ndarray`s of varying size and [internally](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e1ff6268a2e256bdb6cf6c06457456c7c4bd495d/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1047) NumPy is failing to convert this into a float array due to the ragged data, instead creating an array of `object`s*. I can reproduce your error with

```
>>> output = [np.random.rand(3), np.random.rand(4)]
>>> np.savetxt("test", output, fmt='%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/yotam/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1083, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
>>>
```

Whereas if I instead use `output = [np.random.rand(3), np.random.rand(3)]` it works.

(*) i.e. you are getting

```
>>> np.asarray(output)
array([array([ 0.87346791,  0.10046296,  0.60304887]),
       array([ 0.25116526,  0.29174373,  0.26067348,  0.68317986])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, so is there any way to use savetxt with different arrays dimensions? In any case I used the string format and then reconvert the strings to float by  using:                                                                      file=np.genfromtxt('act_lengths.dat',delimiter='\n',dtype='string')
col0=[]; col1=[]; col2=[]; col3=[];
for line in file:
   #removes the '[' otherwise can't convert to float
   line=line.strip('[]')
   columns=line.split()
   col0.append(float(columns[0]))